# Xamarin Android Firebase refresh token

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I implemented Firebase messaging into our Xamarin Android app. The very first time the app was run it called OnTokenRefresh() as excepted. I uninstalled the app and re-ran the debugger which reinstalled the app. This time though, OnTokenRefresh was not called. In fact, I haven't been able to get it to be called a second time for a single device.

I tried making a token service to get the token but it always throws an exception. The method is very simple:

```
 [assembly: 
 Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyApp.Droid.Services.NotificationToken))]
  namespace MyApp.Droid.Services
 {
 class NotificationToken : INotificationToken
 {
    public string GetToken()
    {            
        var token = "";
        if (Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.Instance != null)
            token = Firebase.Iid.FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        return token;
     }
   }
}
```

The exception is thrown on the check if Instance is null.

```
 [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:-119322310>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm
```

I'm calling the service well after the main activity has been created. It's called after the user logs into our app.

I have the google-services.json included in our Android project. I'm pretty certain it's being used since the initial time the app was installed it created the token and called OnTokenRefresh.

```
     [Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        //FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.GetToken();
    }
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        App.NotificationToken.Token = refreshedToken;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    }        
}
```

Comment: watch for https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/253

Comment: Your app receives a registration token when it first registers with FCM while running on a device. This service implements an OnTokenRefresh method that is invoked when the registration token is initially created or changed. When OnTokenRefresh runs, it retrieves the latest token from the FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token property.  OnTokenRefresh is invoked infrequently: it is used to update the token under several circumstance. For more detailed information read the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 you can disable the following preference to ensure that the Firebase Token is refreshed between deployments to your device. This was learned through trial and error.

> Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android > Preserve Application Data/Cache between deployments

Hope this helps.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac (v8.3.11) menu: Visual Studio > Preferences > Projects > Android > Preserve data/cache between application deploys.  Thanks @DFalconer